# Unable to import NSWorkspace from Appkit in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to import NSWorkspace from Appkit in Python2.7 on Mac 10.7.4.
I checked the pynopath in eclipse, its having pyObjc, pip packages, site packages paths but also am not able to import NSWorkspace, even though i can import Appkit.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't work for you?

`from AppKit import NSWorkspace`

`AppKit` should contain `NSWorkspace` unless you're using a non-standard `AppKit` module